# Is it possible to trigger a buzz sound in aria live?

Tags: frontend, accessibility, nvda

I am currently developing a screen reader friendly drag and drop, and I was wondering if it is possible to trigger some kind of buzz noise, when some actions are not possible. E.g.: The user is on the first item and presses "arrow left". Of course, I could use normal Text, but I am curious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This example https://dev.opera.com/articles/accessible-drag-and-drop/example.html from this draft w3c article here https://www.w3.org/blog/wai-components-gallery/widget/accessible-drag-and-drop/. The screenreader will have its own user preferences which might include sound so don't do anything extra here.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect that you can't move an item to the left anymore, you can play a sound using normal javascript with the [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) object and the [`play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) method.

Whether someone is using a screen reader is irrelevant.  There are a variety of reasons why someone might be using a screen reader but since you can't detect if one is being used, you shouldn't base your logic on screen reader usage.

An [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) region is not necessary in this case.